# Windows Phone app using OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-phone

I'm starting to develop an application for fun that uses OAuth2. I'm using this API from Trakt http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#reference/authentication-oauth/authorize/authorize-application

Right now, what I want to do is the authentication, but having some problems with the code.

I have no nuget packages helping, and here's the code I have.

```
System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("https://api-v2launch.trakt.tv/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
webBrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
webBrowser.Navigate(myUri);
```

CLIENT_ID is given by the website API, and it says to put "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" for local tests.

When I run the application, I get a page to login, then I get the "Authorize" and "NO" question. If I click the authorize, It gives me a code, which i'll need to use after.

Though, I'm having an hard time to do a GET method to get that code, or to get the error if the person clicks "NO"

Can you guys help me? With a single GET method, I should be able to do the POST method and continue to develop the application.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.

1) You need to set the URI to: ms-app://{package-security-identifier}
The package identifier is your unique app id.

2) In Trakt you need to add this redirect URI (you do this in your application settings).

Check this Facebook Developer post for details about using their login flow, it is similar: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2